# How to fetch email from contact list of Android phone?

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch various email addresses from contact list of android mobile like work,home.....etc.
for that I am using the code as below but I found in result only zero every time
please help me.
Thanks

```
Cursor email = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                Data.CONTACT_ID + " =" + id, null, null);
        while (email.moveToNext()) {
            emailAdd = email.getString(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK);
            //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)
        }
        Log.v("anim", " emailAdd:    " + emailAdd);
```

and further I need to fetch Organization,nick-name,website also.

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602903/get-the-email-from-contacts-using-autocomplete-textview/8603768#8603768)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cursor emailCur = cr.query( 
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, 
    null,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
    new String[]{id}, null); 
while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
    // This would allow you get several email addresses
        // if the email addresses were stored in an array
    String email = emailCur.getString(
                  emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
    String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                  emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE)); 
} 
emailCur.close();
```